# jQuery take value from input doesnt work

Tags: jquery, html

I have a few inputs type text on my site and i want to take (read) a value from this input when i click on some `<span>` on my site. When i click on span with `id=1` i want to take value from input with `class=1`

I write that script but this only take value from the first input ? Why from not other ? (sorry for my english) ?

```
$("span.button-kopia-make").click(function() {
            var clickID = $(this).attr("id");
            var ileloop = $("input[name=\'ileinputowbudujemy\'][class=+clickID]").val();

            for (var i = 1; i < ileloop; i++) {
            $(\'<p><label for="l_numer">Numer: <input type="text" id="dodany_i_numer" size="8" maxlength="9" name="dodany_i_numer\' + i +\'" value="" /></label></p>\');
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is that you need to concatenate the `clickID` value, instead you are just making the variable name as a part of the selector instead of using its value.

Try:

```
$("span.button-kopia-make").click(function() {
            var clickID = this.id;
            var ileloop = $("input[name='ileinputowbudujemy']." + clickID).val();
                                                           //^__ Class selector
            for (var i = 1; i < ileloop; i++) {
            $('<p><label for="l_numer">Numer: <input type="text" id="dodany_i_numer" size="8" maxlength="9" name="dodany_i_numer' + i + '" value="" /></label></p>');
            }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Becaue `.val()` method will return value of the first input element from the selection provided.

Try storing all the values in an array before iterating over it.

Something like below will put you in the right direction

```
var values = [];
$("span.button-kopia-make").click(function() {
    var clickID = $(this).attr("id");
    var $elements = $("input[name=\'ileinputowbudujemy\'][class=+clickID]");

    $elements.each(function() {
        var elementValue = $(this).value();
        values.push(elementValue);
    });

    for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        $(\'<p><label for="l_numer">Numer: <input type="text" id="dodany_i_numer" size="8" maxlength="9" name="dodany_i_numer\' + values[i] +\'" value="" /></label></p>\');
    }
});
```

Similar fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/NV9j4/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking to loop over each input and do something with the value of each one?  That can be achieved with this code:

```
$("span.button-kopia-make").click(function() {
    var clickID = this.id;
    $("input." + clickID).each( function() {
        // This function will be called on every matching input
        // Get the value of the input
        var i = $(this).val();
        // Do something with it.
        $('<p><label for="l_numer">Numer: <input type="text" id="dodany_i_numer" size="8" maxlength="9" name="dodany_i_numer' + i + '" value="" /></label></p>');
    });
 });
```